# Extract linear equations from R's lm

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lm

Assume I have data with a dependency `y(t)` and parameters `p1`, `p2` and `p3` 
which might influence the value `y(t)`.
I create 3 linear equations which depend on the following combinations of the 
parameters `p1` and `p2` - `p3` has no impact on `y(t)`, that means it follows a random assignment.

The 3 equations are

```
p1 p2   Equation   
 1  1   5 + 3t
 2  1   1 - t
 2  2   3 + t
```

Now, if I call `lm()` based on my random data, I get the following result.

```
lm(formula = y ~ .^2, data = mydata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.14707 -0.22785  0.00157  0.23099  1.10528 

Coefficients: (6 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.83711    0.17548   27.565   <2e-16 ***
t            2.97316    0.02909  102.220   <2e-16 ***
p12         -3.86697    0.21487  -17.997   <2e-16 ***
p22          2.30617    0.20508   11.245   <2e-16 ***
p23               NA         NA       NA       NA    
p32          0.16518    0.21213    0.779   0.4375    
p33          0.23450    0.22594    1.038   0.3012    
t:p12       -4.00574    0.03119 -128.435   <2e-16 ***
t:p22        2.01230    0.03147   63.947   <2e-16 ***
t:p23             NA         NA       NA       NA    
t:p32        0.01155    0.03020    0.383   0.7027    
t:p33        0.02469    0.03265    0.756   0.4508    
p12:p22           NA         NA       NA       NA    
p12:p23           NA         NA       NA       NA    
p12:p32     -0.10368    0.21629   -0.479   0.6325    
p12:p33     -0.11728    0.21386   -0.548   0.5843    
p22:p32     -0.20871    0.19633   -1.063   0.2896    
p23:p32           NA         NA       NA       NA    
p22:p33     -0.44250    0.22322   -1.982   0.0495 *  
p23:p33           NA         NA       NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4112 on 136 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9988,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9987 
F-statistic:  8589 on 13 and 136 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If I only want to condsider parameters with high significance, I would argue to ignore parameters close to zero. If I understand correctly, zero-parameters do not lead to "new lines/levels". I then obtain the following simplified model (Values are rounded for readability, zeros are omitted):

```
            Estimate
(Intercept)        5 ***
t                  3 ***
p12               -4 ***
p22                2 ***
t:p12             -4 ***
t:p22              2 ***
```

I would then reconstruct the approximate theoretical model as follows from the estimate above:

```
p1 p2   Equation                       Result 
 1  1   5+3t                           5+3t   
 1  2   5+3t+p22+t:p22*t               7+5t   
 2  1   5+3t+p12+t:p12*t               1-t   
 2  2   5+3t+p22+t:p22*t+p12+t:p12*t   3+t
```

Now, `7 + 5t` is obviously wrong, but I am not sure about the reason.
I guess, `lm` successively adds the paramters, thus the corresponding model 
`y ~ t:p2` is not contained in the model above?

This question originates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52628373/5784831). You can also find the reproducible and a plot of the 3 equations including random data there.

**Edit**: It seems, that for some reason [ggplot can't handle such results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217047/5784831)

**Edit** for @whuber: The graph looks like the following. red = `7+5t`

[image]

Comment: @user2974951 This means include all intercations up 2-way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11633505/5784831). So this should be correct?

Comment: Never mind then.

Comment: It's unclear what the data-generating process is here. This is my best guess: $y = \begin{cases} 5 + 3t \quad p_1 = 1, p_2 = 1 \\ 1 - t \quad p_1 = 1, p_2 = 1 \\ 3 + t \quad p_1 = 2, p_2 = 2 \end{cases}$

Comment: @shadowtalker the Link is given in the question. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628373/extract-linear-equations-from-lm

Comment: Christoph those $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ have values between 1 and 3. Is that right?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings just from R: `unique(mydata$p1)` has Levels: 1 2, `unique(mydata$p2)` has Levels: 1 2 3 and `unique(mydata$p3)` has 
Levels: 1 2 3

Comment: Could you explain why "`7+5t` is obviously wrong"?  As far as I can tell, it is obviously *correct* because  $7+5t - (5+3t)=3+t-(1-t).$

Comment: @whuber: What do you mean? If I plot `7+5t` it is far too high. All data is well below. See my edit...

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the graph.  Are there any data that lie far from the line predicted for them?  *No.*

Comment: @whuber I fear, I don't understand both of your points: Why do you argue using the difference 7+5t−(5+3t)? To the graph: If I see the dashed red line, I would argue it is far off. If you consider the predicted values, they are very accurate of course. I'd appreciate if you could give an explenation.

Comment: @Christoph the line is far from the points, but the points are not far from the lines. The residuals are very small. If you colour code the lines for similar p1 and p2 then this may become more clear.

Comment: I am not arguing about using the difference: *that's a direct consequence of* your *model.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

Your model at values $p_1 \neq 2$ and $p_2=2$ is just an extrapolation.

The fact that there is no correspondence between the (blue) line at $p_1 \neq 2$ and $p_2=2$ and data is not a problem because there is no data with $p_1 \neq 2$ and $p_2=2$.

In a similar fashion you could compute $y$ values for $t<0$ or $t>10$ and find that the lines do not fit any data points in those regions (because it is extrapolation, ie extending the fit to regions without data points).

[image: extrapolation]

---

When you model your data then you are modelling the 3 lines according to the 3 values of p2 being 1, 2 or 3.

```
  df1 <- data.frame(t = t_m[[1]], y = y_m[[1]], p1 = rep(1), p2 = rep(1),
                    p3 = sample(c(1, 2, 3), length(t_m[[1]]), replace  =  T))
  df2 <- data.frame(t = t_m[[2]], y = y_m[[2]], p1 = rep(2), p2 = rep(2),
                    p3 = sample(c(1, 2, 3), length(t_m[[1]]), replace  =  T))
  df3 <- data.frame(t = t_m[[3]], y = y_m[[3]], p1 = rep(2), p2 = rep(3),
                    p3 = sample(c(1, 2, 3), length(t_m[[1]]), replace = T))
```

That is

```
case    p1    p2    p3
a       1     1     .
b       2     2     .
c       2     3     .
```

The table below seems to be capturing this well enough:

```
Coefficients: (6 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.83711    0.17548   27.565   <2e-16 ***
t            2.97316    0.02909  102.220   <2e-16 ***
p12         -3.86697    0.21487  -17.997   <2e-16 ***
p22          2.30617    0.20508   11.245   <2e-16 ***   
t:p12       -4.00574    0.03119 -128.435   <2e-16 ***
t:p22        2.01230    0.03147   63.947   <2e-16 ***
```

The case $a$ is just the intercept plus the main effect $t$ (no interactions with the $p$'s). The case $c$ is with  $p_1=2$ and the case $b$ is with the $p_1=2$ *and* $p_2=2$.

```
p1 p2   Equation                       Result           Result
 1  1   5+3t                           5+3t             5+3t
 2  2   5+3t+p12+t:p12*t+p22+t:p22*t   5-4+3t-4t+2+2t   3+t
 2  3   5+3t+p12+t:p12*t               5-4+3t-4t        1-t
```

The case below is not present in the data thus not a problem

```
p1 p2   Equation                       Result           Result   
 1  2   5+3t+p22+t:p22*t               5+3t+2+2t        7+5t
```

---

If you would have points p1=1 and p2=2 that do not correspond to the result 7+5t then your model would need a three-way factor t:p12:p22 (which translates as: the interaction effect for the slope of t when p1=2 and p2=2). Although in your particular problem where the parameters p1, p2 and p3 are correlated this might cover the problem as well without the 3-way effects.

Comment: But what about `p1 = 1`, `p2 =  2` where I expect `5+3t+p22+t:p22*t = 7+5t`. My problem is that I (think) I understand everything but my reasoning yields to much! (p2 = 3 has no effect - it's just radom)

Comment: @Christoph I do not see the case p=1 and p2=2 in your data.

Comment: That is true! Thus, it is really not straight forward and I have to consider the existing combinations in my dataset? What if I had one observation p1 = 1 and p2 = 2? I can't imagine, that on out of a 100 observation changes the `lm` result!?

Comment: and as others have noted you have multi-collinearity. That is why you get all those NA values. Just a main effect for the factor $p2$ would be sufficient (but in your analysis this is not obvious since it is crossed out).

Comment: This tends to go towards an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem your problem is not clear. What do all those values mean? Why are you considering the non-existing value p1=1 and p2=2? Why are you not just looking at p2 alone (p2=1, p2=2, p2=3)? What you are doing? Just incorporating all possible interaction effects and seeing what happens (seeing what is significant) is a rather rough approach. It is much more easy to first look at the background/context of the problem to make a more efficient model without the rubbish coefficients (with low interpretability).

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. I need some time to think. BTW: I can't upvote as my reputation is gone ;-)

Comment: Note that if you would like to model the four cases then you will need to use three-way interaction effects to get a term such as t:p12:p22 (which translates as: the interaction effect for the slope of $t$ when $p_1=2$ and $p_2=2$)

Comment: Yes, another good point!

Comment: Your "short" section really hits the nail on the head. Thanks...

Comment: @Christoph, your question was a bit vague and I believe that I got what your problem with it was. But, I would like to stress again that it would be very important to give your model more context and meaning. In statistics the mathematics is just a tool and not the main goal. So problems should not be tackled in a purely mathematical manner. If one has an idea what the three $p$ variables are standing for and how the response could be influenced by them, then a much more logical/meaningful/intuitive model could be created.

Comment: @Marttijn Weterings: I agree. I wanted to analyse traveltimes as I have historic data an OSRM estimates. But before, I wanted to make sure, I understand what I do and I created a simple example to learn. Looking back, this was a really good idea - I think I can start with the real problem now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You have rediscovered the phenomenon of [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

```
car::vif(fit)

# Error in vif.default(fit) : there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

Behold:

```
table(p1, p2)

#    p2
# p1   1  2  3
#   1 50  0  0
#   2  0 50 50
```

$p_1$ is determined entirely by $p_2$. From a linear algebra perspective, the data matrix is not full-rank, i.e. it's *singular* (hence the warning about singularity).

Intuitively, when features are linearly dependent the model has no way to know how much weight to assign to each feature, because at least one feature is an alias of a linear combination of other features.

You have effectively created a variable $p_*$ with 3 mutually exclusive levels. The fix is to drop the base level of $p_*$, not drop the base levels of $p_1$ and $p_2$, which is what R does by default. Here's one way to do it that produces a model with no singularity:

```
mydata$p12 <- paste0(mydata$p1, mydata$p2)
fit <- lm(y ~ (t + p12 + p3)^2, data = mydata)
```

Also, for your sanity, I highly recommend using something like `c("a", "b", "c")` instead of `c(1, 2, 3)`. Otherwise it's really hard to read the default coefficient names.

You might also consider modifying your simulation code so that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are independently sampled.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps your answer (and the other one above) answer my question. I have to think about it. BTW: I can't upvote your question as my reputation is gone...

Comment: @Christoph I believe my answer answers the question, but I am biased. Sorry about your rep. You should get +2 for accepting an answer.